# Playing sounds in Python Quickly without any extra libs?

Tags: application-development, python, quickly, pygtk

I was wondering is it possible to play sounds in Ubuntu using Quickly and Python without including any libs like pygame or pymedia or anything ?

Just the stock packages that come with Python ?

Thank you

Comment: what type of audio files are you interested in?

Comment: mpr or wav .. just any

Comment: [This link](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t337346-how-to-play-sound-in-python.html) suggests you can for just .wav files.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to play wav files in pure Python. [This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/311634) provides an example. It's pretty low-level and not cross-platform though (unless extra code is added). Also, it only plays wav files. If you want more, you really need a library.